# What's the maximum income one can have and not have to file a tax return? [Canada]

Tags: canada, income-tax, small-business

I'm starting a home-based business and make very little.  Do I have to worry about income tax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TaxTips.ca's Federal Tax Rates page](http://www.taxtips.ca/fedtax.htm) has basic information about income tax in Canada, and it states:

> Canadian federal income tax is
>   calculated based on taxable income,
>   then non-refundable tax credits are
>   deducted to determine the net amount
>   payable.  **For 2009, every taxpayer can
>   earn taxable income of $10,320 ($9,600
>   in 2008) before paying any federal
>   tax.** [...]

*(emphasis mine)*

Of course there are also provincial taxes to consider, but generally each province has a basic personal exemption amount.  [TaxTips.ca's page for Ontario rates](http://www.taxtips.ca/taxrates/on.htm) lists $8,881 as the basic personal exemption in Ontario, for 2009.  [Find other provinces here](http://www.taxtips.ca/marginaltaxrates.htm).

Answer (score 2):

According to the [government website](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/flng-blgtns/menu-eng.html), the answer appears to be [no in terms of personal income](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/ndvdls/tpcs/ncm-tx/flng-blgtns/fqs-bnfts-eng.html). However you may want to anyway to start creating RRSP contribution room as well as possibly qualify for GST/HST credit.

If your business is registered you are going to be required to file a tax return for it (and if it is a sole proprietorship [then you would be required to file a T1 regardless](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/sm/sttng/sl-eng.html)).

When all is said and done, it seems that it's probably better to file rather than not file; even if you pay no income tax at least you are sure you won't receive a nasty letter from Revenue Canada in the future :)

Comment: Hi Jedidja.  The second link you posted refers specifically to a small amount of income: $2000, which happens to be below the basic personal exemption.  But, personal income (in general) is not exempt from tax.  But I agree with the rest of your advice; better to file anyway and create the RRSP room & qualify for GST/HST credit.

Comment: Answering the question is a bit tough. The title asks about "not having to file a tax return" and the questions says "worry about income tax".

I believe as long as you don't owe any income tax, you aren't required to file. So all the way up to basic allowance you have listed below. $2000 qualifies as well $10,320 -- the govt site says that you /have/ to file a return if you have to pay tax. Presumably the reverse is also true? :)

Comment: Yes - the way I understand the reverse is:  If you don't owe tax, you don't have to file... **except** if the government *asks* you to prove that you don't owe! :-)

Comment: Totally agree :) Also if the original poster has filed in previous years it may look somewhat suspicious if she does not file this year. There are a lot of variables here; I think we can all agree the best thing is to file regardless.